# Construct a graph from given node degrees

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have to find which of the following values can be the degrees of an undirected graph with 6 vertices:

a) 3 2 2 2 3 3
b) 4 2 2 2 3 2
c) 5 2 2 2 0 3
d) 5 2 2 2 1 2

I only method I found is to try to draw the graph on a sheet of paper and then check if it is possible.
I just need a hint to start this problem, if possible, in other way than drawing each graph.

Comment: Except for those with sum degree odd (a and b), the rest (c and d) can be a graph with 6 vertices. Google for handshaking lemma.

Comment: The handshaking lemma is only a necessary condition and it rules out cases a) and b). But also the degrees of c) cannot form a graph: one node must have degree 5, but only 4 other nodes have edges (one node has degree 0). So only with the degrees of d) a graph can be formed.

Comment: nhahtdh and coproc thank you very much and sorry for the taken time.

Comment: @nha as you have remarked below, for completeness also here: i have implicitely assumed a simple graph. If double edges are allowed then also with the degrees of c) a graph can be constructed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following algorithm decides if a simple graph can be constructed with given node degrees:

1. sort the degrees in descending order
2. if the first degree is 0 (i.e.all degrees are 0) then obviously such a graph can be formed (no edges) and you are done.
3. if the first degree has value `d` (> 0) then the following `d` degrees must be greater 0. If not you are done: no such graph can be formed.
4. take away the first degree (value `d`) and reduce the following `d` degrees by one (i.e. draw the requested number of edges from the node with highest degree to the nodes with highest degrees among the remaining ones - see proof below for correctness of this assumption), then continue with step 1 (with now one node less)

example a)  (can be rejected because of the odd sum of weights, but also the above algorithms works)

```
3 2 2 2 3 3
3 3 3 2 2 2
  2 2 1 2 2
  2 2 2 2 1
    1 1 2 1
    2 1 1 1
      0 0 1
      1 0 0
        -1   not possible
```

example c)

```
5 2 2 2 0 3
5 3 2 2 2 0
  2 1 1 1 -1   not possible
```

example d)

```
5 2 2 2 1 2 
5 2 2 2 2 1
  1 1 1 1 0
    0 1 1 0
    1 1 0 0
      0 0 0  ok
```

What is missing is a proof that if a graph can be drawn with given node degrees, then one of the matching graphs has this property of step 4, i.e. that the node with highest degree is connected with the nodes with next highest degrees.

Let us therefore assume that `A` is the node with highest degree and that it is connected with a node `B` whose degree is less then the degree of node `C` not being connected to `A`. Since `degree(C) > degree(B)`, there is node `D` connected to `C` and not connected to `B`. Thus, there are edges `AB` and `CD`, and there are no edges `AC` nor `BD`. So we can replace `AB` and `CD` by the edges `AC` and `BD` without changing the nodes' degrees.

By repeating this procedure enough times we can make all nodes with the next highest degrees being connected to node with the highest degree.

Comment: There is nothing that says the graph should be a simple graph (no loop). Your algorithm and reasoning to remove option c only applies if the question asks this to be a simple graph. I downvote your post since it doesn't mention about simple graph.

Comment: @nha thanks for the hint: i implicitely assumed a simple graph (no double egdes - i would not call that a 'loop').

Comment: @coproc: A loop is an edge that whose 2 ends are the same. It is a terminology defined on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_%28graph_theory%29). A simple graph will not contain loop and parallel edges (multiple edges connecting 2 vertices).

Comment: Could you please prove that if a graph can be drawn with the given degrees, then one of the matching graphs has the property of step 4?

Comment: @AnkitShubham the proof is already given in the last two paragraphs

Comment: @coproc Could you please give me a direction to figure out how many times the loop should run to check above condition ?

Comment: @NaveenGabriel each loop iteration consists of 4 steps and there are several conditions to check. The algorithm terminates because in each iteration the total sum of all remaining node degrees decreases by at least 2. So the maximal number of loop iterations is the total sum of all node degrees divided by 2.

Answer (score 2):

The [handshaking lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) or degree sum formula is necessary and sufficient condition in this case, since we only care that it forms an undirected graph (orientation of the edge doesn't matter, but nothing is said about loop or parallel edges). Therefore, option c and option d are valid 6-vertex undirected graph.

If the question asks for *simple* undirected graph (loop and parallel edges disallowed), then we need to bring in the algorithm by [Havel/Hakimi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29#Degree_sequence), which is as described by @coproc.